# Spring controller - send html as response

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a loaded jsp page with products and addtocart link against it. I am trying to show the cart in a div in the same page. I want to send html as response. This is what i have done. It just returns the string `<div>output</div>`. Can someone show me how i should do it.

**Controller**

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/addtocart{id}",  produces = "text/plain;charset=UTF-8")
    @ResponseBody
    public String addToCart(@PathVariable("id") int id, @ModelAttribute("cart") Cart cart,Model model)
    {
        Product product = productService.getProductById(id);
        if (product != null) {
            CartLine line = new CartLine();
            line.setProduct(product);
            line.setQuantity(1);
            productService.updateProduct(product);
        }
        return "<div>output</div>"; 
    }
```

**JSP**

```
<td><a id="demo4" href="addtocart${product.id}">Add To Cart</a> </td>

$('#demo4').click(function() { 

                $.ajax({    
                url : '/addtocart{id}',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: "text/html",
                type : 'GET',
                data :{id:id},
                success : function(response) {
                    $('#output').html(response);
                   }
                 }); 
        }); 

<div id="output" style="display:none">
           <h2>Cart Content(s):</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do not create JSP page with HTML code and return it instead?

Comment: I am learning ajax and wanted to know how to do this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also favor the approach with using the view, and separate page even on ajax call. Nevertheless what you're asking is possible, simply change your  `produces = "text/plain;charset=UTF-8"` to produces

```
produces = "text/html;charset=UTF-8"
```

---

There are many other aspects that appear wrong, not related to Spring MVC, so even with the produces corrected you still have to do few corrections to get what you're expecting.

- I think that you're not sending an ajax call at all. You're most likely doing a complete browser redirect. When first read, I was confused that "text/plain" vs "text/html" makes a difference in an ajax response, but now I believe that you're actually redirecting via browser. Change this `<a id="demo4" href="addtocart${product.id}">Add To Cart</a>` into something like this `<a id="demo4" href="#">Add To Cart</a>` and add `return false` to the end of your function. This will execute the function, and the *return* will make sure that the link is not followed
- When you do this you'll notice a few issues with your ajax call as well; firstly, `url : '/addtocart{id}'` should be  `url : '/addtocart${product.id}`
- Capture your response in complete function not in success, and get the output as response.responseText, the response will return fine, but the browser will attempt to parse it as json and fail.
- Your div will remain invisible, you should add some js to toggle that
- One Spring MVC gotcha, your Cart bean seems to have a property called id as well. Because of this, your id path variable should be renamed, otherwise it'll be ignored

This would be something that, if not completly, than much closer to working

```
<a id="demo4" href="#">Add To Cart</a>

<div id="output"></div>
<script>

    $('#demo4').click(function() {

        $.ajax({
            url : '/addtocart${product.id}',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "text/html",
            type : 'GET',
            data :{id:4},
            complete: function(response) {
                $('#output').html(response.responseText);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Renaming PathVariable

```
@RequestMapping(value="/addtocart{productId}",  produces = "text/plain;charset=UTF-8")
public String addToCart(@PathVariable("productId") int productId, @ModelAttribute("cart") Cart cart,Model model)
```

Comment: Now it returns "output". Any other changes i have to do?

Comment: In fact quite a few, I'll edit my response now with a few pointers

Comment: Great ! You are absolutely right. My div is invisible. Why so?

Comment: due to style="display:none"

Comment: Thanks for the great help. I will accept your answer. Just one last one, could u update pathvariable change also in controller here in comments. Just curious.

Comment: Edited in an answer, easier to format. It could be that you'll have to change the type of the productId to String and than convert to int, but try it I'm not 100%

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with AJAX and still return a separate page for your Card, as Slava suggested.

JSP page cart.jsp:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!-- custom html for your cart representation, just an example -->
<div>
  <h1>${cart.headline}</h1>
  <p>${cart.otherProperty}</p>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/addtocart{id}")
public String addToCart(@PathVariable("id") int id, @ModelAttribute("cart") Cart cart, Model model) {
    doSomethingWithCart(cart);

    model.addAttribute("cart", cart); // add cart to model after doing some custom operations
    return "cart"; // resolved to cart.jsp by your view resolver
}
```

This way you are using AJAX but still you are returning dynamic html content (
   adjusted to one specific cart).

Comment: Thanks for workout. But how can i show it in same page? Is it possible?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Sure it is possible to show it in the same page? It works just the way you did it in your question. You do an AJAX request to `/addtocart{id}` but instead of specifying a html response body yourself, it would just return the contents of your cart.jsp with custom card elements. For example `<h1>CART 1</h1>` if `cart.headline` was `"CART 1"`. This is much more common than specifying the response body yourself with a custom html String like in the answer you accepted. Just saying...

Comment: Yes i accept your way is the right one, just wanted to know how to do that way. I should accept your answer too?

Comment: You can only accept one answer and you should accept whichever fits best to your question.